# How to plot multiple boxplots in one chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have this subset which I want multiple boxplot, for each column (ggplot)

```
  Q006 NU_NOTA_CN NU_NOTA_CH NU_NOTA_MT NU_NOTA_LC NU_NOTA_REDACAO
1    B      435.6      512.3      432.4      488.6             420
2    B         NA      409.3         NA      375.3             400
3    B      426.2      578.1      499.9      551.5             500
4    B      489.8      534.3      406.7      527.5             680
5    B         NA         NA         NA         NA              NA
6    B         NA         NA         NA         NA              NA
```

My goal is similar to this> Instead A,B,C... in x axis, I want the NU_NOTA_CN, NU_NOTA_CH, NU_NOTA_MT, NU_NOTA_LC, NU_NOTA_REDACAO

[image: MultipleBoxplots]

Comment: just do `boxplot(df[-1])` where `df` is your dataset and using ggplot2 you will do `df%>%pivot_longer(-1)%>%ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value))+geom_boxplot()`

Comment: it worked, unfortenely I forgot to mention I want in ggplot

Comment: This is basically a wide to long data issue, which can be solved using `gather` or `pivot_longer` from package `tidyr`.

Comment: @neilfws thanks! I did not know the pivot_longer and gather.

Answer (score 2):

Use gather to represent the columns as rows and plot using ggplot as:

```
ggplot(data = df %>% gather(key = variable, value = value), aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable))
```